# dspace duplicate rows in epersongroup2eperson

Tags: dspace

We are using dspace 3.2 and added our own authentication class. This authentication class is called whenever a session is spawned by the first time user. Inside the code, we lookup for the user and add them to the group if they don't belong to that group.

```
EPerson eperson = EPerson.findByEmail(context, email);
if (eperson != null) {
    for (Group group : Group.findAll(context, Group.ID)) {
        if (!group.isMember(eperson)) {
            group.addMember(eperson);
            group.update();
            context.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes in when there are multiple sessions running concurrently and adding the person to the group. This causes a duplicate row entry in the epersongroup2eperson table

```
dspace=> select * from epersongroup2eperson;
id  | eperson_group_id | eperson_id
-----+------------------+------------
 1 |                3 |         10
 2 |                3 |         10
```

Is this a known bug in dspace?

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting a `synchronized` code block around the code above, but the duplicate rows still happens.
So I added a constraint in the table to make the columns unique.

```
dspace=> ALTER TABLE epersongroup2eperson ADD UNIQUE(eperson_group_id, eperson_id);
```